# Adding sub columns to every single existing columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with over 2000 columns with complicated names.

Each column has a price value, with an index of time and I want each column to have additional sub column of 'r'.

For ex.

```
col_1  col_2    col_3   col_4  ...........   col_n
```

to be changed into

```
col_1  col_2    col_3   col_4  ...........   col_n

I price I r I .................................. I price I r I
```

I have tried multi index method, but I am having trouble.

All the columns have a price, and I just want to use existing values for  the new price column, and add extra sub column called `k`.

Comment: Please share a proper sample input and expected output.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by sub-column? Need a better formatted question

Comment: below every single column(col_1,,,,, col_n) I want corresponding 2 columns called 'price' and 'r'.

Comment: I think I kind of get what you're asking but what happens to the data?  What goes into the new `'price'` sub-column?  What goes in to the new `'r'` sub-column?  As a "New Contributor" you should get to know that the people who answer questions are volunteering their time to help you.  It would be in your best interest to make it easy for them to answer by not making them guess at what you want.  Take your time to be clear about what you are asking.

Comment: OK the I there was confusing

Comment: One easy way to do something like this would be `pd.concat({'price': df, 'r': df}, axis=1).swaplevel(0, 1, 1).sort_index(axis=1)` But I suspect that you'll tell me that something isn't quite right because it doesn't get you exactly what you wanted.

Comment: A little more guessing and then I'm done, I promise.  Use `pct_change`: `pd.concat({'price': df, 'r': df.pct_change()}, axis=1).swaplevel(0, 1, 1).sort_index(axis=1)`

Comment: I already have a price values for every column. My existing dataset has a price values already. I just want to add new sub column 'k' along with the existing 'price' under every column. I already wrote a function to calculate 'k' for every corresponding 'price' but just having trouble adding 'k' to every column